# Can I use a 220v soldering iron on 110v?

Tags: voltage, soldering

I ordered a 110v soldering iron, but received one marked 220v 60w with a usa-compatible plug. If I plug into 110, will it still heat up?

Comment: Vote to close. That said, it will heat up since its basically a resistor. But less current than expected will flow and it won't heat up as much (by how much I dont know, since the heating element possibly doesnt have linear resistance wrt to voltage and temperature)

Comment: Not for soldering...

Comment: your question makes absolutely no sense ..... you have the iron in your hand .... instead of plugging it in and observing the result, you ask this question ..... is there any information that you did not mention?

Answer (score 1):

Very likely yes, it will heat up. But it might not get hot enough to do any proper soldering. As the voltage is halved, so is the current. That means the power of 60 W will be divided by a factor of 4 so your 60 W iron will now only behave as a 15 W iron.

There are small soldering irons rated for 15 W so 15 W might be enough for some soldering jobs. It depends on how the iron is build, if it has a lot of metal it might take very long to heat up and/or radiate too much heat to become hot enough for soldering.

Anyway, you can safely try it out, as the mains voltage is lower than the iron's rated value it is safe to try.

Comment: Yes. I had a backup 60W 220V soldering iron that would heat up enough to solder on 110V. Not guaranteed to work on all models or ambient temps though. Also at 220V it would heat up too much for electronics work.

Comment: That is my experience as well. Powerful irons get too hot. Low power ones take too long to heat up and aren't suitable for large connectors etc. For serious soldering a temperature controlled iron is a must.